# Background not starting at top

Tags: css

So I am working on a website hosted at http://development.randomrab.com

The background starts off at the top whenever I have the background attachment set to fixed. However, I would like the background to scroll. Whenever I set the background attachment to scroll, the background image starts off at the center of the page. As in, you have to scroll down to see the background. I tried changing the background position to top, center top, top center, and none of that worked.

My CSS code looks like this:

```
body {
color: #FFF;
font-size: 14px;
font-family: Arial, Tahoma, Verdana;
margin: 0 auto 0;
padding: 0;
line-height: 24px;
background-color: #0C0807;
background-attachment: scroll;
background-image: url(images/Rab_bg.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: top;
}
```

Comment: Your `background-position` is set to `center` on that page. I changed it to `top` and it worked fine.

Comment: You are required to post a complete, minimal example of the problem here, not your web site: [mcve]

Comment: @Rob I provided my website but I also showed my code too.

Comment: A link to your web site will help no one when your web site changes or disappears. Read the link I gave you. Your CSS is not a complete representation of the problem.

Comment: @Aydin Yes, on my website I have it positioned center and attachment fixed because right now that looks the best. Whenever I use the code posted her to StackOverflow, it throws everything off.

Answer (score 0):

`background-attachment: scroll` is the same as `background-attachment: initial` ([more info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-attachment)). If you reset your background attachment and position, you'll reset the background image to the top. Then you can manipulate it later to your liking.

```
background-attachment: initial;
background-position: center top;
```

And this what you get:
In Chrome:
[image: Randomrab Chrome Screenshot]

In Firefox:
[image: Randomrab Firefox Screenshot]

Comment: It still looks a little off.

Comment: It looks like it shifts it to the left or right. I need it to be at the top and centered.

Comment: Edited with `background-position:top center`

Comment: I did background-position: top center and background-attachment: initial. It still wants to put the background in the middle of the page leaving the top part blank.

Comment: My apologies, try `background-position: center top;`, because `background-position` takes values as _XY_ coordinates, not the other way around.

Comment: Still the same issue.

Comment: Ah. Works in Firefox, but not in chrome